# How can I make certain pixels transparent in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I checked the brightness of each pixel with the for statement and tried to make it transparent if the brightness was over 100.
But invisibility does not work.

look at the code, the fourth of image_al [x, y] is alpha. What should I do?
(If you I the value of bgr rather than transparency, it  changed.)

```
image = cv2.imread('cat.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

image_al=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
image_hsv=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
for x in range(image_al.shape[0]):
    for y in range(image_al.shape[1]):
        px=image_hsv[x,y]
        print(px)
        if px[2]>100:
            px=image_al[x,y]
            image_al[x, y]=[px[0],px[1],px[2],255] #image_al[x, y]=[b,g,r,alpha]
cv2.imshow('image2',image_al)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Development environment: PyCharm, Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to avoid `for` loops when processing images in Python - they are very slow, inefficient and hard to read. Numpy and OpenCV are vectorised - they process entire images in optimised `C` and are fast.

So, you can convert to HSV and extract the V channel, then simply threshold it and merge it in as the alpha layer:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load Image
im = cv2.imread('temple.jpg')

# Convert to HSV and take V channel
V = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[...,2]

# Threshold V channel at 100 to make alpha channel (A)
_, A = cv2.threshold(V,100,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Stack A channel onto RGB channels
result = np.dstack((im,A))

# Save result
cv2.imwrite('result.png',result)
```

[image]

[Photo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ta_Prohm#/media/File:Angkor_SiemReap_Cambodia_Tha-Prom-Temple-01.jpg) by CEphoto, Uwe Aranas or alternatively © CEphoto, Uwe Aranas
CC BY-SA 3.0

**Result**

[image]

If you want the bright pixels transparent, change to this:

```
_, A = cv2.threshold(V,100,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
```

Then the result will be:

[image]

**Keywords**: Python, image processing, HSV, Hue Saturation and Value, add alpha channel, merge alpha channel, create alpha channel, OpenCV